# Tables and needed columns in Joomla 4

Tags: joomla-4.x, database

On the Page
https://www.dionysopoulos.me/book/com-tables.html#com-tables-get-object I read:

> The table MUST have the following columns:
> `parent_id`. The primary key of the parent node. Provides adjacency list data for nodes.
> level. The depth level of the node in the tree.
> `lft`. The left value of the node for managing its placement in the nested sets tree.
> `rgt`. The right value of the node for managing its placement in the nested sets tree.
> alias. The alias of this node used to construct the full text path, forward-slash delimited.

Is that really true?

There are many tables in Joomla itself that do not contain the `rgb` and `lft` columns. For example, those of com_content:

https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/4.2-dev/administrator/components/com_contact/sql/install.mysql.utf8.sql

Comment: This text is about nested tables using `Joomla\CMS\Table\Nested` class.